# Scala: Print content of function definition

Tags: scala, apache-spark, macros

I have spark application and I implemented DataFrame extension -

```
    def transform : Dataframe => Dataframe
```

,so app developer can pass custom transformations in my framework. Like

```
    builder.load(path).transform(_.filter(col("sample") == lit(""))).
```

Now I want to track what was happened during spark execution: 
Log:

- val df = spark.read()
- val df2 = df.filter(col("sample") == lit("")))
- ...

So, the idea is keep log of actions and pretty-print it at the end, but to do this I need somehow get the content of Dataframe => DataFrame function. Possibly, macros can help me, but I am not sure. I actually don't need the code(however will appreciate it), but just get the direction to go.

Comment: I doubt this will be easy. You could perhaps look into [showCode](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.5/scala-reflect/scala/reflect/macros/Universe.html#showCode(tree:Printers.this.Tree,printTypes:Printers.this.BooleanFlag,printIds:Printers.this.BooleanFlag,printOwners:Printers.this.BooleanFlag,printPositions:Printers.this.BooleanFlag,printRootPkg:Boolean):String), but this will never print out the original code (your lambda could be extremely complex, call other functions etc.). Are you sure that `df.queryExecution.optimizedPlan` doesn't already cover your need?

Comment: Unfortunately no, the main driver for all of that is next: at the end of spark job, it should print action log somewhere, which i can pickup and execute in zeppelin or spark-shell without ceremony and debug if someth wrong...